# how to use changeDetection onPush with observable

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I am absolute beginner in Angular2,

this are my components,how to update this.product Array in HeaderComponent , whenever buynow() is triggered in FoodDetailsComponent

```
export class HeaderComponent {
    products: Array < any > ;
    cart: Array < any > ;
    Tabs: Array < any > ;

    constructor(public ShopDataService: ShopDataService) {
        this.products = this.ShopDataService.get();
    }
    ngOnInit() {}
}


export class FoodDetailsComponent {
    @Input()
    foodDetail: any;
    constructor(private ShopDataService: ShopDataService) {

    }
    buynow(product) {
        this.ShopDataService.add(product);
    }
    ngOnInit() {}

}
```

And i have  few doubts how change Detection work,changeDetectionStrategy is only for child-parent component.how about sibling component works?

Comment: show your html, how these components are related. and where do you use `onPush`

Comment: this is main html,<div class="container">
  <nbits-header></nbits-header>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

Comment: read [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f) to understand how onPush works

Comment: try like this
public changedetect: ChangeDetectorRef

this.changedetect.detectChanges()

Comment: this main html,
<div class="container">
  <shopkart-header></shopkart-header>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

shopkartHeader html ,
<div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span>{{products.length}}</span>
            </button>
</div>

in router-outlet,
  <div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let food of foodDetail">

                
                    
   <div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click) = "buynow(food)">Buy Now!</button>
                 
   </div>
 </div>

Answer (score 1):

you need to subscribe to the service when you get the data.

```
this.ShopDataService.get().subscribe( result => {this.products = result});
```

also please share the code in your service.